# How to use an array in a text-to-speech script

Tags: javascript, php, text-to-speech

Hello stackoverflow Community,

I am working on a Survey which uses Text-To-Speech components. Usually they look like this:

```
<img src="picture.jpg" border="1" input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak('spoken_Text_here', 'Deutsch Female');"  class="button1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text_behind_Button?
```

Now, I have a Database with all the Elements which will be "spoken" (or: to be used in the TTS script) and insert them in my survey software with

```
$key = 'A1';
$tts = dbGet($key);
```

So far so good. Now I would like to take the first element of the array $tts und put it in the TTS script.

```
<img src="picture.jpg" border="1" input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak('<?php $tts[0] ?>', 'Deutsch Female');" class="button1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Text_behind_Button?
```

As a result I would like, that when you click on the button, the script takes the string from the Database and inserts it the TTS code. This way above obviously doesn't work. So I guess that I have to change the array in a string which can be read. Unfortunatly, I dont have the knoledge how to do that.

Ideas, hints and criticism (more or less) are welcome!

Best wishes

Comment: `<?php $tts[0] ?>` “does” nothing, maybe you want to actually output the value here? `<?php echo $tts[0]; ?>`

Comment: Seems TYPO mistake. `<?php $tts[0] ?>` needs to be `<?php echo $tts[0]; ?>`

Comment: or `<?= $tts[0] ?>`  seems cleaner & short.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I tried to print the string with "echo" as well. Unfortunely doesnt make a sound. Also <?= $tts[0] ?> doesn't work. the script without php and with a normal string works fine, so I guess the php part is the troublemaker.